# How to safely remove a Ubuntu-Windows dualboot?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-8, bootloader

I tried to do this one time before, but it completely failed. I wiped all of it's partitions, and reclaimed the partitions within Windows, however, that messed up GRUB and I couldn't get back the the Windows Boot Manager. Then, I had to remove Windows and completely wipe my HDD, and reinstall Windows. I've redone a dual boot, but I'm looking to remove. Can someone please help me fix this problem so that it doesn't happen again?

Comment: Tried all of that last time.

Comment: If you try again, and have a problem, you will have to ask a more specific question or perhaps ask in a windows support site.